# 100% height minus variable height

Tags: css, height

I'm stuck with a problem: I have basicly four divs:

```
<div id="a">Variable Height: 45px or 90px</div>
<div id="b">fixed height: 50px</div>
<div id="c">Has to fill up remaining</div>
<div id="d">Variable Height: 85px or 40px</div>
```

Also: #c may not be under, over #d. It has to fill up until #d's top. Paddings can be used, the inside of #c just may not go under/beneath/over #d.

And here's the CSS:

```
* { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
body, html { height:100%; }
#a { min-height: 45px; width:100%; background: red; max-height:90px;  }
#b { height: 50px; width: 100%; background: orange; float:left;}
#c {/*Here how to fill up remaining*/ }
#d { min-height: 40px; max-height: 85px; background: green; float:left; position:absolute; bottom:0px; }
```

I can't use javascript, unfortunately, so I hope there are some possibilities with CSS!

**EDIT:**

I tried -webkit-calc, but that didn't work because that value has to be static.

Using Safari 7.0.2
Cheers,
Douwe

**EDIT**
Just fixed the problem with a table.. Required a little more out-of-the-box than i thought! Anyways thanks!

Comment: Please review this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Why can't you use JS?

Comment: Because the width of the #a and #d changes with functions. And to implement the rule again and again won't work. I prefer JS though, but in this case it just isn't possible!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height of c to auto or 100% works for me in Chrome. What is not working for you?

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gejumexe/1/edit?html,css,output) If you change the content of the two variable height divs the height of c changes correctly.

CSS:

```
* { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
body, html { height:100%; }
#a { min-height: 45px; width:100%; background: red; max-height:90px; overflow:hidden;  }
#b { height: 50px; width: 100%; background: orange; float:left;}
#c { height: 100%;}
#d { min-height: 40px; max-height: 85px; background: green; float:left; position:absolute; bottom:0px; width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Because if you set the height to 100%, it will overflow and take the 100% height of the body.

Comment: It doesn't do that in my demo?

Comment: In mine it does, unfortunately :-(

Comment: @douwe12345 is the difference due to the browser or code?

Comment: I opened your demo, but the demo has the same problem: so i think i can say browser.

Comment: Ok. I understand the theoretical problem with this scenario, and I was surprised that the code worked in Chrome.

Comment: Do you have a solution? Because i've been breaking my head on this for a week now.